# Python Kivy Label with textvariable

Tags: python, variables, label, kivy, kivy-language

I am new in programming with kivy and I could need some help with my code.

What I want to do is run the function draw_card() and set the label text in Screen2 equal to the variable some_var mentioned in draw_card, when my second button in screen2 is pressed.

I have got 3 files to do so. The main.py with my python code, the screens.kv with my kivy code and the appvariables.py with my function and dictionary for draw_a_card().

Is there also a way to use a usual variable instead of the card_drawn_dict in the appvariables.py to output my drawn card?

Thank you guys very much.

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, WipeTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from AppVariables import *



class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenThree(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):

    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_three = ObjectProperty(None)


class ScreensApp(App):

    def build(self):
        m = Manager(transition=WipeTransition())
        return m


    def draw_card(self, *args):
        draw_a_card(self, *args)
        some_var = card_drawn_dict[1]
        print(some_var)
        screen_one.mylabel.text = some_var


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScreensApp().run()
```

**screens.kv:**

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    screen_one: screen_one
    screen_two: screen_two
    screen_three: screen_three

    ScreenOne:
        id:screen_one
        name: "Screen1"
        manager: screen_manager


    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two
        name: "Screen2"
        manager: screen_manager


    ScreenThree:
        id: screen_three
        name: "Screen3"
        manager: screen_manager

<ScreenOne>:
    Button:     
        text: "Start"
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen2'
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "y":0.2}

<ScreenTwo>:
    Button:
        text: "Screen 3"
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen3'
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "y":0.1}

    Button:
        text: "Karte ziehen"
        on_press: app.draw_card()
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "y":0.3}

    Label:
        id: mylabel
        text: ""
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "y":0.6}

<ScreenThree>:
    Button:
        text: "Screen 1"
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen1'
```

**appvariables.py:**

```
# Module: AppVariables.py
from random import randint

# Global variables
card_dict = {1:'Ace of Hearts', 2:'King of Hearts',
             3:'Ace of Diamonds', 4:'King of Diamonds',
             5:'Ace of Clubs', 6:'King of Clubs',
             7:'Ace of Spades', 8:'King of Spades'}
card_drawn_dict = {}

# Functions
def draw_a_card(self, *args):
        random_number = randint(1, 8)
        if random_number in card_dict:    
                card_drawn = card_dict[random_number]
                card_drawn_dict.update({1:card_drawn})
                #print(card_drawn)
                del card_dict[random_number]
        else:
                while not (random_number in card_dict):
                        if random_number == 1:
                                random_number = 8
                        else:
                                random_number -= 1 
                card_drawn = card_dict[random_number]
                card_drawn_dict.update({1:card_drawn})
                del card_dict[random_number]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Populate Screen_Two's Label

Use `self.root.screen_two.ids.mylabel.text = some_var`

## Use variable

A deck of card has 52 playing cards, 4 suits (Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs), and thirteen ranks of each suit.

## Example

### AppVariables.py

```
from random import randint

# Global variables
cardSuits = ['Spades', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs']
courtCards = ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
cardRanks = ['Ace'] + ['{}'.format(x) for x in range(2, 11)] + courtCards
cardsDrawn = []


# Functions
def draw_a_card(self, *args):

    # a deck of card has 52 playing cards
    if len(cardsDrawn) >= 52:
        print("\tcards_drawn=", sorted(cardsDrawn))
        return 'Drawn 52 cards!'

    # Example set of 52 playing cards; 13 of each suit clubs, diamonds, hearts, and spades
    suit = randint(1, 4)
    rank = randint(1, 13)
    card = '{0}-{1:02d}'.format(suit, rank)

    if card not in cardsDrawn:
        cardsDrawn.append(card)
        return '{0} of {1}'.format(cardRanks[rank-1], cardSuits[suit-1])
    else:
        # recursive call
        return draw_a_card(self, args)
```

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from AppVariables import *


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenThree(Screen):
    pass


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_three = ObjectProperty(None)


class ScreensApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Manager()

    def draw_card(self, *args):
        some_var = draw_a_card(self, args)
        print(some_var)
        self.root.screen_two.ids.mylabel.text = some_var


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScreensApp().run()
```

### screens.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import WipeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.WipeTransition

<Manager>:
    transition: WipeTransition()

    screen_one: screen_one
    screen_two: screen_two
    screen_three: screen_three

    ScreenOne:
        id:screen_one
        name: "Screen1"

    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two
        name: "Screen2"

    ScreenThree:
        id: screen_three
        name: "Screen3"

<ScreenOne>:
    Button:
        text: "Start"
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen2'
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "y":0.2}

<ScreenTwo>:
    Button:
        text: "Screen 3"
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen3'
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "y":0.1}

    Button:
        text: "Karte ziehen"    # Draw Card
        on_press: app.draw_card()
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "y":0.3}

    Label:
        id: mylabel
        text: ""
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "y":0.6}

<ScreenThree>:
    Button:
        text: "Screen 1"
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Screen1'
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02 - 52 cards drawn]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. :)